# Can't run a linux .sh script with python subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am trying:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["file.sh"])
```

But I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 85, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["file.sh"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However when I try and run the script from the shell `bash file.sh` it works. So I'm confused as to why it doesn't work?

I am not committed to using subprocess so if there are other options please let me know.

Comment: Does `file.sh` (as opposed to `bash file.sh`) work from the command line? No? Why do you expect `subprocess.call(["file.sh"])` to work then?

Comment: I just tried adding `(["bash file.sh"])` and exactly the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `call` function of the `subprocess` package runs the command specified in arg as a list of strings (to simplify).

To call your file you have put in your script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sh", "file.sh"])
```

Comment: Is the script file.sh in the same directory as your python script ? Else you must replace "file.sh" with the path to the file. No prob.